# Assigning object to an object of different class

Tags: c++, class, member, assignment-operator

Given 2 classes `class Euro` and `class Dollar`

I've overloaded the assignment operators so object of same type pass their private value to each other.

MRE:

```
#ifndef EURO_H
#define EURO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Dollar.h"

class Euro
{
    public:
        Euro();
        ~Euro();
        Euro(int temporary);
        Euro(const Euro &object);
        Euro operator = (const Euro &other);
        friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const Euro &object);

    private:
        double euro;
};

#endif // EURO_H
```

&

```
#ifndef DOLLAR_H
#define DOLLAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

#include "Euro.h"

class Dollar
{
    public:
        Dollar();
        ~Dollar();
        Dollar(int temporary);
        Dollar(const Dollar &object);
        Dollar operator = (const Dollar &other);
        friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const Dollar &object);

    private:
        double dollar;
};

#endif // DOLLAR_H
```

Now I'm trying to define the behavior that euro gets converted into dollar and the other way around when assigning object of type Euro to an object of type Dollar.

But when declaring another assignment operator like `Euro operator = (const Dollar &object)` it doesn't know type Dollar even though I included Dollar.h file.

Why is that and how can I achieve this without declaring both classes each others `friend` ?

Comment: Maybe use a forward declaration. And please make a [mre]

Comment: please post a [mcve]. My guess is that you have a cyclic dependency, but we need to see the code

Comment: btw `operator=` should return a reference not a copy of `*this`.

Comment: This is still not reproducible. Where is `Dollar.h`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably facing the problem of *cyclic dependency* between two classes.

Your Euro class is including "Dollar.h" while most probably your Dollar class is including "Euro.h". One of the includes would be blocked by the include guard (`ifdef` / `pragma once`). Only one would appear above the other, they cannot be both above each other.

The solution is using **forward declaration**.

Add:

```
class Dollar; // forward declare class Dollar to allow using it
```

above the Euro class, and vice versa.

The forward declared type is now considered an *incomplete type* - the compiler can use it before seeing the actual declaration of it, but only for specific usages: the forward declaration helps in using the class in function signatures and for having a pointer or reference member of this type, but not for having an actual value type member or for methods implemented inside the header that need to know the "complete type".

If you get an error on using an *incomplete type*: if it is on function implementation using the incomplete type - move the function implementation to your cpp file, where both headers are already included and the type is considered by the compiler as a complete type.